# Calculating the mean in a Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Let {X(t); t $\ge 0$ } be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda=2$. Determine $E[X(1)X(2)]$.

How to determine the mean of those random variables?

Because I think in this case I cannot do $E[X(1)X(2)]=E[X(1)]E[X(2)]$.

Then what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use independence of increments:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_1X_2]=\mathbb{E}[X_1(X_2-X_1)]+\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2-X_1]+\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$$
The three expectations can now be easily computed using the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2-X_1$.

Comment: and $\mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2-X_1]+\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] =(2)\mathbb E(X_1)+6=(2)(2)+6=10$ is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.